Actualizacion de dependencia Play Core Maven a una versión compatible con Android 14
Hola alguien sabe como resolver esto, me llego de google play
¡Actualice su dependencia de Play Core Maven a una versión compatible con Android 14! Su biblioteca Play Core actual es incompatible con targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), que introduce un cambio incompatible con versiones anteriores en los receptores de transmisión para mejorar la seguridad del usuario. Como recordatorio, a partir del 31 de agosto, Google Play requiere que todos los lanzamientos de aplicaciones nuevas tengan como objetivo Android 14. Actualice a la última dependencia de la versión de la biblioteca Play Core para evitar fallas de la aplicación: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore- migración
Es posible que no puedas lanzar versiones futuras de tu aplicación con esta versión del SDK para producción o pruebas abiertas.
Paquetes de aplicaciones y APK afectados:
versión: 13 (5.1.0), versión: 1.0.0
Si tiene preguntas sobre este SDK, comuníquese con el proveedor del SDK.
